# Way to recreate all python class instances each time program loops

Tags: python, class, reset

For a python RPG, I have player_module.py, which contains all classes, methods and functions.

```
class RingOfRegeneration(Regeneration):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = "Ring of Regeneration"
        self.item_type = "Rings of Regeneration"
        self.regenerate = 1
        self.sell_price = 10000
        self.buy_price = 10000

ring_of_regeneration = RingOfRegeneration()
```

Right now I have over 30 class instances. The class instances and their attributes are referenced throughout the module, (which is about 10,000 lines at this point). I have a loot_dict within the module from which random items may be found, which simply contains the instances:

```
loot_dict = {
            'Armor': [leather_armor, ....],
            'Rings of Regeneration': [ring_of_regeneration...],
...         }
```

I also have the main.py loop. Class instances like swords and rings can be found in the dungeon, and can be enhanced. For instance, a ring of regeneration can be enhanced throughout the game to self.regenerate = 2, 3...etc.
My problem is, when the player dies and is given the choice to play again, breaking out to the top level loop and restarting the game, if loot is found, it still has the 'enhanced' values. I want to simply reset or recreate all class instances every time the player restarts the loop and as a beginner, I can't figure out a way to do this without exiting the program and restarting it from the command line. I have been unable to grasp any solutions from similar topics. Lastly, if I have painted myself into a corner, as a last resort, is there a way to simply re-run the program from within the program?

Comment: You should add a constructor at the beginning of the loop that creates all the objects. Objects are garbage collected (deleted) once the reference is lost. Read more about [lifetime and scope of objects](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html)

Comment: Cpt.Hook, So, import the classes from player_module.py to main.py and then import the instances from main.py to player_module.py?

Comment: Importing? You should import the modules that define the class once (as in `from foo import Foo`), but then create it where they are used (as in `foo = Foo()`).

Comment: Right now I have all classes and created objects in player_module.py. You are suggesting I create a file for each class? Creating the objects at the beginning of the loop as you initially suggested would involve me putting foo = Foo() in the main.py file..which would necessitate importing them over to player_module.py....

Comment: I don't get what you mean by importing. For me it's a fixed term taht refers to import statements. Please provide a minimized example. 
But generally: Yes: It is cleaner to have smaller modules and smaller classes. So a file per class (or closely related bunch of classes) makes sense for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loot dict has in real reference to objects and if you assign to player character any object from `loot_dict` you assign reference to the same object what is in your `loot_dict`. (Just like a pointer in cpp).
You need to create new instance of object every time the player gets new item.
To achive it You can do something like this:

```py
loot_dict={'Rings':[RingOfRegeneration]}
```

Now u can call it:

```
item_class = random.choice(list(loot_dict.keys())) 
new_item_instance = random.choice(loot_dict[item_class])() #Calling class __init__ method
```

`new_item_instace` is now fresh base statistics.

Comment: Right now I am using           
                key = random.choice(list(loot_dict.keys()))
                rndm_item_index = random.randrange(len(loot_dict[key]))
                found_item = loot_dict[key][rndm_item_index] I will change and report back, thank you.

Comment: Ok, I see I must change the objects to classes. This will take some work. I will report back, thank you, Pawel.

Comment: Now I see what I was doing wrong. Even after reading your solution, it did not click right away. I was randomly calling the created objects themselves rather than randomly creating them. I can't tell you how much I appreciate it. I am an absolute beginner and this really helps me learn. Thanks again.